# How to change textValue of node without removing its childNodes

Tags: php, dom

Imagine this HTML :

```
<html>
      <head><title>Nice page</title></head>
      <body>Hello World <a href=http://google.com>This is a link</a>
            <br />
            <a href=http://www.google.com> this also
                <img src=wrong.image> and here
            </a>
     </body>
</html>
```

When I try to put all the text of my links in capital letters, it erases the img tag of my link tags.

```
<html>
       <head><title>Nice page</title></head>
       <body>Hello World <a href=http://google.com>THIS IS A LINK</a>
            <br />
            <a href=http://www.google.com> THIS ALSO AND HERE</a>
      </body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP I use :

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("index.html");
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
foreach($elements as $elem)
{
    $elem->nodeValue = strtoupper($elem->nodeValue);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

How can I preserve the children?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an xpath query to specifically get the text nodes within the links.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("example.html");

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$linkTextNodes = $xpath->query('//a/descendant::text()');
foreach ($linkTextNodes as $node) {
    $node->textContent = strtoupper($node->textContent);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```